# EJB as WebService context-root gone

Tags: web-services, glassfish, ejb, jax-ws

I'm working on a project with JAX-WS.

When I annotate my endpoint class with `@WebService` the WSDL is marked in console like

```
.../<context-root>/XXXService?wsdl
```

When I add `@Stateless` on those endpoints the WSDL is not marked in console and the actual address is

```
.../XXXService/XXXEndpoint?wsdl
```

Is this normal or expected?

**Update**

For further readers.

I couldn't find any resolution. I decided not to use mixed `@Stateless`+`@WebService`. I split those `@EJB`s and `@WebServices` for clear module separation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What youre experiencing is expected behaviour. It's a different matter if the service s not functional. When an EJB 3.x stateless bean is deployed as a WS, it's naming defaults to what you see there,

```
Servername/SIBnameService/SIBName.
```

The reason for this is obvious: EJBs don't operate within the context of a web application and so cannot be addressed as such. You can customise the default name using the `serviceName` attribute on the `@WebService` annotation

Look at [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/GMOxKB/what-is-the-endpoint-address-of-my-web-service.html) from apache